# What possible value (or danger) might this usage, non-usage, or abusage of System.Runtime.CompilerServices be?

Tags: c#, namespaces, compiler-services

In the legacy spaghetti, I came across this spicy meatball:

```
//Keep around, might prove useful.
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    public sealed class IsVolatile
    {
        private IsVolatile()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possibly of any value? Or perhaps a better question, possibly of any harm (to retain)?

Comment: It's an empty shell (no functionality).  Why would it be of any use, except as a reminder of the skeletons in the closet?  Is it used anywhere?

Comment: Bah, it isn't even named correctly.  Nuke it.

Comment: Is there any code in the class you omitted?

Comment: This class has been around in mscorlib since .NET 1.0. If you are not reimplementing mscorlib for a specialized application, then I believe you can safely remove that declaration.

Comment: @George: no, that's all there is to it; as mentioned, an "empty shell"

Comment: @Robert: I commented it out, and it compiles, so apparently it's just a relict of prior daydreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah - looks like you've got a situation similar to the "I want LINQ syntax, but I'm in 2.0 land", where you could "turn on" LINQ syntax via:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

Only here, you're enabling use of the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: There's a comment below it:
// use: public volatile bool test;
//               ^
//               |-- volatile allow OS to interpret value.

Comment: That's sure to be *really* old code...I think `volatile` has been supported by VS as far back as...what, VS2005?

Comment: Oh, and it's purely for the compiler, if that needed to be said - you won't find any actual *code* referencing that class.